# Odoo 15 Find tax_ids Inside the account.move.line (Invoice) Model

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, odoo-14, odoo-15

Good day, hope everything's well.

I'm trying to find the value of `tax_ids` (Many2many field) inside the `account.move.line` model but i can't seems to find anything. I already access the `psql` of the database but i cant find `tax_ids` too.

I accessed that `account.move.line` model with ORM like this :

```
    def _post(self, soft=True):
        for move in self:
            ....
            account_move_line = self.env['account.move.line'].search([('id', '=', int(move.id))])
            print(account_move_line.tax_ids) #this find nothing
```

could someone please elaborate how is it possible to access id of the tax that applied to, in this case, an invoice line record?

Edit : Sometimes this ORM fetching the ID and sometimes it doesn't. But most likely it's not fetching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to find the value of tax_ids (Many2many field) inside the
> account.move.line model but i can't seems to find anything. I already
> access the psql of the database but i cant find tax_ids too.

`tax_ids` in `account.move.line` model is a Many2Many field, which is stored separately as another table in the database. This kind of relation field mostly be named something like this `(main_table)_(related_table)_rel` (ignore the parentheses). For example, this particular case's table is `account_move_line_account_tax_rel` since its main table is `account_move_line` and the related table for that specific field is `account_tax`. Inside the relation table, you will almost always find 2 fields mapping both ids together. For this case, it is going to be `account_move_line_id` and `account_tax_id`.

> I accessed that account.move.line model with ORM like this :
>
> ```
> def _post(self, soft=True):
>     for move in self:
>         ....
>         account_move_line = self.env['account.move.line'].search([('id', '=', int(move.id))])
>         print(account_move_line.tax_ids) #this find nothing could someone please elaborate how is it possible to access id of the tax
> ```
>
> that applied to, in this case, an invoice line record?
>
> Edit : Sometimes this ORM fetching the ID and sometimes it doesn't.
> But most likely it's not fetching.

Accessing a field via ORM always works as you intended if it is implemented correctly. In your code, you are searching `account_move_line` by `id` but you are trying to search it with `move.id`, which I assume it is `account_move` since you got the data *sometimes*. If you can access the lines that you want correctly, you will see that `account_move_line.tax_ids` will always give you the correct `tax_ids`. From what your code looks, I think you are trying to search the lines by its `account_move`. Therefore, your domain should be `[('move_id', '=', int(move.id))]` instead.

Comment: thank you so much! i'm using self.env['account.move.line'].search([('move_id', '=', int(move.id))])[0].tax_ids is now working as expected! lifesaver!

Comment: `move.id` should be an integer, you don't need to use `int()`